# Marketo REST API: Update Lead -> upload a file associated to a lead

Tags: rest, marketo

I have a working system creating and updating leads in Marketo using their REST API. I have looked for information on if it is possible to upload a file that can be associated to a lead in Marketo - but I have not found anything about uploading a file with the REST API.

Does anyone know if this is possible? And if so, if there is any documentation on this process?

Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

Marketo does not have a built-in concept of linking a lead to a file.  This is something which could be accomplished with a custom object, though.  You'd create a custom object definition that links to a lead and includes a URL field pointing your desired file.  Custom Activities could also be a reasonable option here if you only need a historical record of the link which does not need to be updated.

Comment: Hmm, ok... thank you for the answer and suggestions.